# Response.Redirect throwing error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having an issue with a response.redirect call.

Error:

> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted. at
>   System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal() at
>   System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo) at
>   System.Web.HttpResponse.End() at
>   System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse) at
>   System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url) at
>   Web.AdminUser.LoginHandler.OpenIdLogin() in
>   c:\Builds\15\Digital\main\Sources\Web\Public\LoginHandler.aspx.cs:line
>   113

The redirect is happening in a `try - catch` statement and I can't seem to figure out the right way to do it.

```
try
        {
            if (Request.Form.HasKeys())
            {
                Global.Logger.Info(string.Format("OpenIdLogin_Has_Keys"));

                string request = Request.Form.GetValues("token")[0].ToString();

                Rpx rpx = new Rpx("123412341234", "https://login.youwebsite.com/");


                var xml = rpx.AuthInfo(request).InnerXml;

                //lblx.Text = xml.ToString();
                XElement xdoc = XElement.Parse(xml);

                if (xdoc.Element("email") != null)
                    xdoc.Element("email").Value = "";


                int userId = SaveMember(xdoc);
                if (userId > -1)
                {
                    //add the user id to session for later
                    Session["CurrentUserId"] = userId;
                    Session["UserLoggedIn"] = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Session["UserLoggedIn"] = false;
                }

                articlePath = String.Format(articlePath, Section, Name);
                Response.Redirect(articlePath, false);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Global.Logger.Error(e);
            articlePath = String.Format(articlePath, Section, Name);
            Response.Redirect(articlePath, false);
        }
```

Comment: Its hard to figure out what is wrong without seeing the actual code

Comment: What does you good look like in LoginHandler.aspx.cs, especially in the area of line 113?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try using this technique:

```
Response.Redirect("...", false);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

This should avoid the `ThreadAbortException`, but still complete the request.

Answer (score 0):

you can say `Response.Redirect(“home.aspx”, false);` and it will not stop the request.

but it will continue to execute. so careful when using  `Response.Redirect(“home.aspx”, false);`

If you pass false you will not get the error but it will NOT end the request

correct me if I’m wrong. But code like this

```
public void Btn_Click() 
{
    if(count == 0)
    {
          Response.Redirect("OutOfStock.aspx", false);
    }
    Prospect.Save(-1, purchaceDate);
}
```

Even if count == 0

```
Prospect.Save(-1, purchaceDate);
```

will always run. And will save a new prospect when you might expect it to stop execution

Comment: AFAIK, this will not happen, the thing that will be terminated or continued is the Response stream itself, not the executed code, so the code above will not hit "Prospect.Save()" method if the redirection happened.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the below

```
Response.Redirect("URL", false);
```